# Strange ListView behaviour on data set change

Tags: android, listview

In my application I'm using number of items checked on list.
I'm also updating items on list, deleting them and inserting new ones.

Case scenario:

1. I'm removing item from list used by adapter
2. I'm calling `notifyDataSetChange`
3. I'm refreshing `my component`
4. `My component` is asking `mMyListView` for number of checked items
5. `View` is returning old number

I was browsing android sources and find out that even if I call `notifyDataSetChange`, `handleDataChanged` method (some `package-protected` `AbsListView` method) is not call immediately, but later. And this is the function responsible for changing number of checked items.

I resolved it by extending `ListView` with my own class with only one change:

```
@Override
public long[] getCheckedItemIds() {
    handleDataChanged();
    return super.getCheckedItemIds();
}
```

To get checked items number, I'm calling `mMyListView.getCheckedItemIds().length` (because of API level I cannot use `getCheckedItemCount`).

Now it works, but I don't like this solution. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your case scenario. What is `my component`? What is `view` that returns `old number`?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare I updated qutestion. `My component` is fragment of my code which calls `mMyListView` [`view`] `getCheckedItemIds().length` and shows this number somewhere. `view` is `mMyListView`: instance of standard android `ListView`.

Comment: How do you asking for number of checked items?

Comment: @Geralt `mMyListView.getCheckedItemIds().length`